# Searching for scalable storage solution

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation, nosql, storage, scalability

In one project I save statuses of processing in MySQL table:

```
`id`  `name`  `email`  `has_apples`  `has_bananas`
 1     Bob     a@b.c    1             0
 2     Mike    c@d.e    0             1
 3     John             1             1
```

`name`+`email` pair should be unique.
For now everything works fine. But the table grows rapidly, and currently it contains about 100m rows.
According to the development needs I have to add, lets say, `has_oranges` column.

Altering such a big table is painful, requires downtime and it doesn't look like that the MySQL is a right tool for this problem.

Even more, the number of such type of data will grow in the future.
I'm looking for a long-term scalable solution, which will allow:

- fast search by id
- fast search by name
- unique control of the `name`+`email` pair
- column scalable
- storage scalable

I'm not familiar with NoSQL solutions, but it seems that maybe that's the way to go.

Comment: Dude... [How Twitter stores 250 million tweets a day using MySql](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/12/19/how-twitter-stores-250-million-tweets-a-day-using-mysql.html)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not familiar with NoSQL solutions, but it seems that maybe that's the way to go.

I think you're way off in what requires NoSQL and big data. By at least a few orders of magnitude:

1. 100 million is not much, and *grows rapidly* needs to be quantified.
2. Schema changes also need to be quantified, do you need schema?
3. Speaking for PostgreSQL, extending a table does not result in the table being rewritten.

## Using PostgreSQL

Following my [own advice and creating an email type](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/165923/2639) here is an example,

```
CREATE EXTENSION citext;
CREATE DOMAIN email AS citext
  CHECK ( value ~ '^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&''*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$' );

CREATE TABLE contacts (id,name,emailaddress)
AS
  SELECT
    id::int,
    id::text || ' First Last',
    (id::text||'first@last.com')::email
  FROM generate_series(1,100e6) AS gs(id);
```

Keep in mind, some of that time is spent validating the email addresses against the HTML5 spec. Anyway, that all finishes in `720882.332 ms` or 12 minutes on my rusty laptop. Keep in mind, that's without the indexes. Now we add the indexes.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON contacts (name, emailaddress);
ALTER TABLE contacts ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ANALYZE contacts;
```

Tada, test data done.

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = 424242;
   id   |       name        |     emailaddress     
--------+-------------------+----------------------
 424242 | 424242 First Last | 424242first@last.com
(1 row)

Time: 4.534 ms

SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE name = '424242 First Last';
   id   |       name        |     emailaddress     
--------+-------------------+----------------------
 424242 | 424242 First Last | 424242first@last.com
(1 row)

Time: 5.224 ms

ALTER TABLE contacts ADD COLUMN has_apples bool;
ALTER TABLE
Time: 8.612 ms

ALTER TABLE contacts ADD COLUMN has_bananas bool;
ALTER TABLE
Time: 14.813 ms
```

Adding columns like that is probably not a good idea, why not use the [`jsonb` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html)

```
ALTER TABLE contacts ADD COLUMN fruits JSONB;
ALTER TABLE
Time: 7.957 ms

CREATE INDEX ON contacts USING gin(fruits);
Time: 24928.756 ms

INSERT INTO contacts (id,name,emailaddress,fruits)
VALUES
  (100e6+1, 'Evan Carroll', 'foo@whatever.test', '{"bananas":true}');
INSERT 0 1
Time: 8.630 ms

SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE fruits @> '{"bananas":true}';
    id     |     name     |   emailaddress    | has_apples | has_bananas |      fruits       
-----------+--------------+-------------------+------------+-------------+-------------------
 100000001 | Evan Carroll | foo@whatever.test |            |             | {"bananas": true}
(1 row)
Time: 5.188 ms
```

Etc., Not sure what you mean by "scalable storage", or "unique control of the name+email pair".

Sizes are also manageable. For $70, you can fit the entire index in RAM.

```
Table: 7301 MB
Index: Pkey: 2.1GB, name/email unique: 6.4GB, gin/json: 102MB.
```