# When does a table get an oid?

Tags: postgresql, database-internals, ctas

I'm wondering when a table acquires an oid. Is it only when the transaction commits? Or does it have a hidden oid prior to commit? Especially in the context of a `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table OIDs are assigned quite early in table creation, and are definitely present by the time the `CREATE TABLE` finishes (before xact commit), since the row is visible in `pg_class` by then.

The new `pg_class` row (and its oid) are *not visible to concurrent transactions* until commit, though.

It's not clear why you care, though. It shouldn't matter.

Comment: I want to understand it, and I would also like to know if I can use something like [`pgstattuple`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstattuple.html) to see the insertion status of large table creations (a billion rows) with CTAS. I do them pretty often for this site, just finished an answer with [100 million insertions in CTAS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/175233/2639).