# Adding constraint on data

Tags: postgresql, constraint, psql

I created a table called `customer`, which consists of one attribute called `email`.

Then I would like to add a constraint to `email` attribute.
**Following is my coding:**

Create table customer 
( email varchar(100));

**Here is my constraint:**
"@" must be included in the email

However, I don't know how to add this constraint. 
I am total new to psql. Thank you very much!

Comment: You may be interested in the answers on [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68266/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-an-email-address-in-postgresql) that deals with the best way to store email addresses in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
ALTER TABLE customer 
    ADD CONSTRAINT email_chk CHECK ( email like '%@%' );
```

should work. If email is mandatory you should make it NOT NULL as well. For a more thorough handling of the email-domain, check out the link:

[What is the best way to store an email address in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68266/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-an-email-address-in-postgresql)

that @MaxVernon posted in his comment.