# Can't we make a non-primary key or non-unique key in a table as a foreign key in another table?

Tags: postgresql

I have got 4 tables named Blood_Bank,Consumer,Employee and Donor.Blood_Bank has SB as primary key which is a dummy attribute.I did not take bank_id as primary key since it can be repeated.To identify each repeated values,I have added one more column called SB.I took bank_id(neither primary nor unique)as the foreign key.These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Blood_Bank(
    SB varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    bank_id varchar(10) UNIQUE,
    bank_name char(25) NOT NULL,
    bank_add varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    bank_phone varchar(12) NOT NULL,
    b_id varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    b_grp varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    b_quantity varchar(4)NOT NULL,
    b_RHfactor varchar(5)NOT NULL);


CREATE TABLE Consumer(
    c_id varchar(20)PRIMARY KEY,
    c_name char(20) NOT NULL,
    c_add char(50) NOT NULL,
    c_blood varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    c_phone varchar(12) NOT NULL,
    bank_id varchar(10) REFERENCES Blood_Bank(bank_id));


CREATE TABLE Employee(
    emp_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    emp_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    emp_dept varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    emp_salary varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    emp_desgn varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    bank_id varchar(10) REFERENCES Blood_Bank(bank_id));

CREATE TABLE Donor(
    d_id varchar(20)PRIMARY KEY,
    d_name char(20)NOT NULL,
    d_blood varchar(15)NOT NULL,
    d_phone varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    d_gender char(20) NOT NULL,
    d_age varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    bank_id varchar(10) REFERENCES Blood_Bank(bank_id));
```

But,it is giving me the following error for the tables Consumer,Employee and Donor.

> ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "blood_bank".Please help.

Comment: If `Blood_Bank.bank_id` "can be repeated", how can it be a `UNIQUE` key? And, you say that `Blood_Bank.bank_id` is not unique, but it *is* defined as `UNIQUE` in your table definitions. Which is true? As shown (and as Evan Carroll noted), your code should work as shown at this point; if `Blood_bank.bank_id` is not actually `UNIQUE`, then it won't.

Answer (score 1):

First don't use `varchar(x)` in PostgreSQL, just use `text`. Second, all of your `char(x)` are likely wrong. In SQL, that means store whitespace padding. This is wasteful and a bad idea. You likely do not want `char(x)`. Also, your `id` columns should probably be `int` (if you're designing this schema new).

You just need to drop your tables and try again. Your code works fine.

Comment: What's the benefit of using TEXT over VARCHAR(nn) in PostgreSQL?

Comment: It doesn't have an arbitrary length constraint and check. In PostgreSQL they're implemented the same way so there is no point in constraining a consumer's name to 20 characters.

Comment: Thanks, so it is a convenience thing where you don't know the maximum length. In situations where you want to constrain the attribute to a maximum length then VARCHAR(nn) would be a good choice?

Comment: Yes, but when most developers say they *want to* what they really mean is that they have a totally arbitrary guess that they want to make law, which doesn't usually make sense anyway so most pg developers just use `text`. If I'm not writing to a spec, I just use text too.

Comment: @Lennart it would be slightly better to use `text` with a `CHECK` constraint on ita length than `VARCHAR(n)`. It saves some time when you want to change the value of `n`. (dropping a constraint and adding another does not need a table rewrite).

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I don't think changing the length of the varchar(n) requires a table rewrite either. Irrc think that's old and bad advice.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ actually i asked this question before here, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/189890/does-changing-the-length-limit-type-modifier-of-varchar-result-in-a-table-or

Comment: Right. In some cases it needs a table rewrite (when you make the size smaller). Apparently you didn't remember the essence of your answer ;)

Comment: Right. "in some cases". Good correction.