# Convert postgres varchar[] to text[] without downtime

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, alter-table, ddl, online-operations

As I discovered in researching [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/293904/112479), converting a column from `varchar(100)[]` to `text[]` requires a table rewrite and rebuilding indexes.

Is there a way to manage this conversion without the locking and rewriting through some catalog trickery like that used in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48693373/754254)? Particularly interested in version 10 if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *should* work with a simple catalog modification, since `text` and `varchar` are the same:

```
UPDATE pg_attribute
SET atttypid = 'text[]'::regtype, atttypmod = -1
WHERE attrelid = 'mytable'::regclass AND attname = 'mycolumn';
```

But, as you know, catalog modifications are unsupported, and if I forgot something and it breaks, you might be in trouble.

Comment: Will definitely test this before deploying :) For completeness, [link to pg_attribute docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html)

Answer (score 1):

RDS does not support catalog modifications, so have to do this manually after all :( Here are the steps to follow, adapted from [this post](https://medium.com/braintree-product-technology/postgresql-at-scale-database-schema-changes-without-downtime-20d3749ed680). To change `orig_column` from `varchar(100)[] not null` to `text[] not null`:

1. Upgrade to version 12 at least
2. Create a `text[]` column called `new_column`, which allows nulls
3. Create `BEFORE UPDATE` and `BEFORE INSERT` triggers which copy `orig_column` into `new_column` and `orig_column` into `old_column` (see code at bottom)
4. Update existing to rows to fill in `new_column` with `orig_column`
5. Create copies of any index using `orig_column`, but using `new_column` instead, **concurrently**
6. Add a CHECK constraint `(new_column IS NOT NULL)`, deferring validation
7. Validate constraint
8. Update `new_column` to be `NOT NULL`
9. Drop the CHECK constraint
10. In a trx with `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table, rename the columns to `old_column` and `orig_column`
11. Set `old_column` to be nullable
12. Drop the triggers
13. Drop indexes referencing `old_column` **concurrently**
14. Drop `old_column`
15. (optional) Rename indexes to match previous naming convention

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_function_name() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  IF (to_jsonb(NEW) ? 'new_column' AND NEW.new_column IS NULL) THEN
    NEW.new_column = NEW.orig_column;
  END IF;
  IF (to_jsonb(NEW) ? 'old_column' AND NEW.old_column IS NULL) THEN
    NEW.old_column = NEW.orig_column;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```