# postgres boolean function and check constraint

Tags: postgresql, constraint

I been using postgres for a while.  Mostly simple stuff.

Now trying to implement a small perl function to check for a single valid email address.

My employees table should have either a single valid email address, or none (ie empty, zilch).
I assume none means undef(email)

My sample code below.

I'm trying to return FALSE only if the given variable is NOT an email address.

The function appears to correctly check a given email address, BUT wrongly returns FALSE if email is blank or empty.

Grateful for any help to show me how to do this the-right-way.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION email_valid(email text) RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
use Email::Address;
my $answer = 1;
return $answer if (undef ($_[0]));
my @address = Email::Address->parse($_[0]);
$answer = scalar(@address);
return $answer;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plperlu;

ALTER TABLE employees
ADD CONSTRAINT check_email CHECK (email_valid(email) = TRUE) ;
```

*Edit.  Here's the revised procedure commented below, in easier to read format.*  :-)

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.email_valid(email text) RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
    use Email::Address;
    my $input = shift;
    return('TRUE') if ($input eq '');
    my @address = Email::Address->parse($input);
    return (@address == 1 ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE');
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plperlu`

This is a different question to the similar previous question at [What is the best way to store an email address in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68266/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-an-email-address-in-postgresql)

I need to also allow null or blank email address, whereas other question and answer will require valid e-address.

Comment: Assume that we know zero Perl. What does the function return when the parameter is an empty string?

Comment: Try `return $answer if ((not defined $_[0]) or ($_[0] == ''));`
Or `return undef if ((not defined $_[0]) or ($_[0] == ''));`. Returning NULL will still work for the `CHECK` constraint.

Comment: What is your table employee structure ? Please post ddl

Comment: Improved code as per below.
This *seems* to be working as intended, further testing to follow, before I can mark this Question as Answered.

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION email_valid(email text)

  RETURNS boolean AS

$BODY$

# procedure to check valid email address

# TRUE if NULL or only 1 email address

# otherwise FALSE

 use Email::Address;

 my $input = shift;

 return('TRUE') if ($input eq '');

 my @address = Email::Address->parse($input);

 return (@address == 1 ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE');

$BODY$

LANGUAGE plperlu `

Comment: @Arkhena


Structure of employees table is plain vanilla.   Usual details, Name, Address, etc, and column called "email".

Comment: Oh, you're right, my bad.. Should I delete my answer as it's not accurate ?

Comment: Thanks to all who helped me find a good solution to my question.